# Function modification does not reflect in output

Tags: javascript, node.js, qunit

I have the following code I want to test.

```
module.exports = {
    // src/code.js
    cl: function(param){
      this.foo = function(){
        return "foo" + param;
      };
    },

    bar: function(param){
      var t = new cl(param);
      console.log(t.foo());
      return t.foo();
    }
};
```

The test is as follows:

```
// tst/test.js
var code = require("../src/code");

QUnit.module("Testing");

QUnit.test("test", function(assert){
    assert.equal("foo", code.bar(""));
});

QUnit.test("test mock", function(assert){
    code.cl = function(param){
      this.foo = function(){
        return "Mock:" + param;
      };
    };

    console.log(code.cl.toString());

    assert.equal("Mock:", code.bar(""));
});
```

I am running the test using the following command:

```
qunit -c ./src/code.js -t ./tst/test.js
```

The logging of the function body prints out the following:

```
function (param){
    this.foo = function(){
        return "Mock:" + param;
    };
    }
```

However, the second assertion fails.

```
Actual value:
Mock:
Expected value:
foo
```

The behaviour seems inconsistent.

Comment: That looks like a [non-atomic test setup](http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#keeping-tests-atomic) to me.

Comment: @Pointy: I attempted to make it atomic. The results seem to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What looks wrong to me is the object creation of **cl** inside **bar**. As you are referencing a method of the object, you must add **this** with it.

```
module.exports = {
    cl: function(param){
      this.foo = function(){
        return "foo" + param;
      };
    },
    bar: function(param){
      var t = new this.cl(param); //updated cl call with this
      console.log(t.foo());
      return t.foo();
    }
};
```

Try this and let me know if your test passes.

**EDIT:**
 `var t = new this.cl(param);`
 Here, previously **cl** was referenced without **this**. I am not sure why it did not throw any error. I tested similar code in browser console.

```
test = {
    cl: function(param){
      this.foo = function(){
        return "foo" + param;
      };
    },
    bar: function(param){
      var t = new cl(param);
      console.log(t.foo());
      return t.foo();
    }
};
test.bar("");
```

It threw an error saying that **cl** was not defined.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cl is not defined
    at Object.bar (<anonymous>:10:15)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

As you are exporting an object which contains **cl** method, you must reference it with **this** inside the **bar**.

Comment: This works as per expectation. Thanks for the answer. If you could just add the explanation as to which ```cl``` function was being referred when ```this``` keyword was not added, I can mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry for not giving much explanation at first. I have updated the answer with comment and additional explanation. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: The code I posted worked perfectly fine for me. I am also surprised why the behaviour is so. If there is a reference error in browser console, it should also appear when run from node.js environment.